# Exchange - export all incoming and outgoing email addresses to csv

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I have a client who wants to mine their MS Exchange data to capture all incoming e-mail addresses (and outgoing).  Outlook isn't an option, and we tried Add a Contact but we need a different solution.

I know we can export all of the mailboxes smtp addresses - but we don't need that.. When a new e-mail comes in to a specific mailbox, we want to harvest it.  Obviously we would only do it for specific users lest we bring the server to it's knees.

**We don't want to use Outlook**.. Rather, we want a server side solution, Powershell etc, that exports to a CSV for post processing purposes. And we don't want this to be a part of any archive process either (unless it doesn't actually complete an archive process - not my rules, the client's..)

Using exchange 2007 - but would rather move to 2010 etc..

Is there any way to export these external addresses via powershell to a csv file on a nightly,  if not weekly basis, for specific or all mailboxes?  (GUI is not an option either)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just enable (by default it's done) message tracking on you server using  `Set-TransportServer` (on Hub Transport server or Edge Transport server) or `Set-MailboxServer` (on Mailbox server) depending on the kind of server your are working on as explain in [this Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).

Then you can have a look to  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking` directory.

On the server side your can read this file as a CSV file using :

```
import-csv MSGTRK20130627-1.LOG -Header date-time,client-ip,client-hostname,server-ip,server-hostname,source-context,connector-id,source,event-id,internal-message-id,message-id,recipient-address,recipient-status,total-bytes,recipient-count,related-recipient-address,reference,message-subject,sender-address,return-path,message-info,directionality,tenant-id,original-client-ip,original-server-ip,custom-data
```

I just found the header in the forth line, and you must ignore the first four lines.